# CSS inline block item wrap around

Tags: html, css, css-float

Without using absolute positioning, is it possible to achieve the effect in **Figure 2** below?

Specifically how can box 4 fit snugly below box 1 like in **Figure 2**, and not be on a new line like in **Figure 1**.

[image]

**html**

```
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="apt" style="height: 200px;">1</div>
    <div class="apt" style="margin-top: 20px;">2</div>
    <div class="apt" style="margin-top: 60px; height: 100px">3</div>
    <div class="apt" style="height: 200px">4</div>
    <div class="apt">5</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.apt
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.calendar
{
    width: 160px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #666;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5gdyab10/

Comment: You can only use absolute positioning to achieve that. The reason being that CSS constructs the layout along a main axis (usually the horizontal one), and whenever the axis overflows, it clears the previous line—therefore resulting in the gap you see. You might need to use CSS columns, but that will change the ordering of your elements while achieving the intended effect. Otherwise you will have to use a JS-based solution, like Masonry.

Comment: Is a flexbox solution acceptable?I am no fan of absolute positions when it comes to responsive sites.
Things like this are ideally resolved with flexbox imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **flexbox**.

Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/5gdyab10/4/**

**HTML**

```
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="apt" style="height: 200px; order: 1;">1</div>
    <div class="apt" style="order: 3; margin-top: 20px;">2</div>
    <div class="apt" style=" height: 100px; order: 4; margin-top: 60px;">3</div>
    <div class="apt" style="height: 200px; order: 2;">4</div>
    <div class="apt" style="order: 5;">5</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.apt
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 4px;
}

.calendar
{
    width: 160px;
    height: 490px;
    background-color: #666;
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I reduced height of container so item `2` would go to other column but you can do that or increase `height` of items `1` and `4` or `2`. Also i had to set custom order of items.